# Openbox, limit area for fullscreen windows or hide gtk title bar

Tags: openbox, panel, fullscreen, tint2

I am using Openbox with tint2 panel.
I want to run the Midori browser to see only a web page without the gtk title bar of the browser.

For example I run midori with this command:

```
$ midori -a https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

If I set

```
<decor>no</decor>
```

in openbox rc.xml, the title bar of Midori is shown anyway.
So I am searching a way to not whow the title bar of the gtk application.

A possible solution is to start Midori in fullscreen mode whit this command:

```
$ midori -a https://unix.stackexchange.com/ -e Fullscreen
```

but in this case the tint2 panel is covered by the fullscreen window.

There is a way to limit the area for the fullscreen window in Openbox?
I tried with margin option in rc.xml, but this doesn't work with fullscreen windows.

Answer (score 0):

To run the Midori browser without its GTK title bar while also preserving the tint2 panel, you can use the wmctrl command line utility.

First, you need to find out the window ID of the Midori window. In a terminal window, run the command wmctrl -l, which will list all the windows currently open. Look for the window with an app name of 'Midori'. Note down the window ID and then run the command `wmctrl -i -r <Window_ID> -b remove,fullscreen` to exit fullscreen mode.

Now you can start Midori with the command `midori -a https://unix.stackexchange.com/ -e Fullscreen --hide-menubar`. This will open the Midori window in fullscreen mode, hiding the GTK title bar and preserving the tint2 panel.

Comment: --hide-menubar is not a valid option for Midori 9.0. I want to use Midori because I like the option of reload the default page when the browser is not used: `-i, --inactivity-reset=SECONDS     Reset Midori after SECONDS seconds of inactivity` but essentially I want to see only a web page without browser menu and controls. If it is not possible to do with Midori I can use another software.

Comment: You can start Chromium in kiosk mode with the following command:

$ chromium --kiosk https://unix.stackexchange.com/